# What is an "assembly" with regards to Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, assemblies

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app/) and in it, it says

> Be sure to replace YOURASSEMBLY with the actual name of your Assembly.

The line it is referring to is this:

```
 System.IO.Stream src =
    Application.GetResourceStream(
      new Uri(@"/YOURASSEMBLY;component/" + dbName,
              UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
```

What am I supposed to put here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always find the name of your assembly if you right-click your project, go to properties. On the Application tab, there's a field called "Assembly name".

The link to the article doesn't work, but you should remember to set the file you're trying to load as an "embedded resource" under "Build action" under properties for the given file.

Comment: Just 'Resource', not embedded.

Comment: Thanks guys but I still get a NullReferenceException! Frustrated!

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen I guess that depends on what you're trying to load. When using Application.GetResourceStream I believe you can load embedded resources http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I'm trying to load an SQLite database, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Silverlight supports loading both with that. But WP7 only uses "Content" and "Resource". So if "Embedded Resource" works, it'll be the same as the default action which is "Resource".

Comment: @billynomates Your NullReferenceException is because  Application.GetResourceStream returns null, so when you're doing ".Stream" it fails.

Comment: And it returns null since, tada, you specified a invalid Uri.

Comment: @billynomates is your db file placed in the root of your VS project? Assuming the dbName variable is purely the name of the file, it "should" work. Check the build action of your file and its placement in your project

Comment: @Claus Ah, I see. Well, I'm sure I *am* specifying an invalid URI, but how do I know what the valid one is?

Comment: You read the URL, and use your sense of logic. We can't tell you without seeing your code. You could take a screenshot of your project, and post the full path you attempted with, but it won't necessary help.

Comment: @Claud. Yeah, obviously. The original question, I guess, was already answered. This other stuff should probably be taken elsewhere. Thanks anyway, guys.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to the [.NET assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly), that is the executable/dll you have produced.

Use the name of the assembly - so if it is called "MyMobileApp.dll", the assembly will be "MyMobileApp", though you should check in the project properties.

Comment: In WP7 you won't build an exe. The code will be compiled into a DLL